# Pushing local merge commit to modified remote branch

Tags: git

I locally merged a feature branch into the master branch and wanted to push. However, while I was merging, the remote master branch had been updated. How do I best deal with this issue?

As I see it, I can

- **undo my local merge** and redo it using the updated remote master
- **create a second merge** by joining my local merged master branch and the updated remote master together

The first option means doing all of the merging work all over again, while the second option makes the git log quite messy by adding a second merge commit.

Comment: You can use on master branch : `git pull origin master --ff-only --rebase`. It will try to put your commit ahead last commit on remote master without merge commit.

Comment: @Calumah if you --rebase then --ff-only doesn't do anything. Also if the tracking is already set you don't need to repeat the remote and branch every time. So probably just git pull --rebase.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes it's ignored of course, but I put it by reflex to avoid merge commit without --rebase option, sorry about that. So yes short version is `git pull --rebase` ;)

Comment: @Calumah I had the same idea, but git seems to remove the merge commit when rebasing. Looking at the git log after a rebase, it is then no longer clear that a merge happened